# Cannot access validateError string after isValid() call

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to implement a backbone model validate function, I am following the api here:
http://backbonejs.org/#Model-isValid

```
var newModel = new Model({ item: this.$('#itemValue').val() });

if (!newModel.isValid()){
    // prints entire object in console, with the validateError string, as expected.
    console.log(newModel);
    // these both work fine as well
    console.log(newModel.get('item'));
    console.log(newModel.attributes.item);
    // this is undefined
    console.log(newModel.validateError);
}
```

I can't convert it to a JSON object because the validateError string is outside of the attributes of the model.

So I am confused, how do I access the validateError string in my instance of my backbone Model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs say you should use [`validationError`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validationError) (not `validateError`).

So change the last line to `console.log(newModel.validationError);`